# Factorial in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I want to find a factorial of a number which is less than 8 using this code. but this is not working can anyone help me out?
This was my home work. i tried but it is printing same character again and agian..

```
.model small_  
.stack_

.data_  
no db 1h_ ;  
counter db 1_  
string1 db "Please Enter the No. to calculate factorial (0~8): ","$"  
string2 db "Factorial is: ","$"  

.code  
main proc  
mov ax,@data  
mov ds,ax  
mov dx,offset string1  
mov ah,09h  
int 21h  
mov cl,1  
loop1:  
cmp counter,3  
ja End1  
mov ah,01h  
int 21h  
sub al,48  
inc counter  
mov no,al  
cmp no,8  
ja loop1  

Factorial:  
cmp no,cl  
je display  
mul al,cl  
inc cl  
jmp factorial  

Display:  
mov ax,@data  
mov ds,ax  
mov dx,offset string2  
mov ah,09  
int 21h  
mov dl,al  
add dl,48  
mov ah,02h  
int 21h  
End1:  
mov ah,4ch  
int  21h  
main endp  
**_End main _**
```

Comment: show us your 8 lines of code

Comment: Who said it was just 8 lines? ;)

Comment: I'm sorry but we don't do [Whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)).

Comment: Come on guys, give him a few minutes to edit his question and add the code before you call in the sarcasm brigade :)

Comment: @us2012 He's had six so far and counting.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add code.

Comment: @Mujahid Which character is printed over and over again? Can you enter the number just fine and it only breaks when printing the result?

Comment: @us2012 yes it works just fine when i enter the character..problem is with factorial label or printing label. which i'm not able figure out.

Comment: @us2012 character is something like Pi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least three major problems in your code:

- `8!` is too large to fit into `AL`.
- Your printing code only works for numbers up to `9`. You're adding 48 and then printing as a character, which is fine for single-digit, but even for `10` it can't work. You need to write a complete section for printing numbers (or maybe use one that your professor provided)?
- You are storing the result of your computation in `AL`, but you overwrite it when you do `mov ax, @Data`.

Comment: But it should work for 2 or 3..but its not working at all..:(

Comment: @Mujahid That's true, it should work for 2 or 3. Are you sure `mul al,cl` is valid 8086 assembly? I thought that `mul` took one operand and `al` was implicit, so it should be just `mul cl`?

Comment: still the same problem..how can i see a line by line execution just like debugging in c++ VS6..

Comment: Still the same problem. can i see line by line execution of this code just like debugging in VS6 in c++?

Comment: @Mujahid I think I found your problem. You are storing the result in `AL`, but you have to overwrite `AX` and therefore `AL` in order to output the `Factorial is` string. The solution would be to store the factorial result somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
GetFactorial proc N:DWORD 
    mov eax,N
    mov ebx,eax 
    @L:
    dec ebx
    Test ebx,ebx
    je @End
    imul eax,ebx 
    jmp @L
    @End:
    ret
GetFactorial endp
```